# JSON path expression

Tags: xpath, jsonpath

I have the following JSON payload:

```
{
    "inputs" : [{
            "attributeX" : [{
                    "id1" : "value11",
                }, {
                    "id1" : "value12",
                }
            ],
            "attributeY" : [{
                    "id" : "valueY1",
                    "attributeZ" : [{
                            "pathZ" : "/Path1/Path2[00163E038C2E1EE299C1C394370BCFA0]/Description",
                            "value" : "valueXYZ",
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to write a JSON path expression so that I want to get the value of pathZ. However part of the value within the [] is dynamic. Is there anyway of specifying a wild card within the following JSON path expression ?

```
$.inputs.[*].attributeY.[*].attributeZ[?(@.pathZ=='/Path1/Path2**<HOW_CAN_I_SPECIFY_A_WILDCARD_HERE>**/Description')].value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex in the JSON Path expression to match the start and end of the PathZ value, without matching the middle.  This is what the expression would look like:

```
$.inputs.[*].attributeY.[*].attributeZ[?(new RegExp('^/Path1/Path2.*/Description$').test(@.pathZ))].value
```

I have tested this using the online JSON query tool here: http://www.jsonquerytool.com/sample/jsonpathregex